# how to connect two mysql tables in which I am inserting data in same time

Tags: php, mysql

How to connect two mysql tables in which I am inserting data in same time?

I have table ***customers*** which is my app table, and I have ***user*** which is used by library I use for my framework, this library handles users and authorization.

I wanted to have **user_id** (which is **id** from ***user***) in ***customers***, but I am creating those two tables in same time.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You are probably inserting records, not creating tables in the "same time". There's no parallelism in MySQL, 1 query gets executed after another - that's how it works. You should probably clarify your question to more detail.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am inserting records in those two tables, my mistake. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the php command mysql_insert_id gives you the id of the last record inserted into a table.  So from my undestanding if your inserting a user you could get the id then insert that into another table?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Or have I understood your question wrongly?

Comment: This will probably provide quick fix for my problem. I didn't know about this command. Thanks!

Comment: @Nemanja i don't think you should see this as a quick fix. getting your insert id after an input is the most common and fast way if you want to directly add something that links to what you just inserted in another table.

Comment: you are probably right, what are the odds to create 2 users at the almost same time and mess up with ids.

Comment: @Nemanja Even if 2 users are created at the same time it won't be a problem, because `mysql_insert_id()` is connection specific. So if user 1 is created and directly after it user 2 (trough another session) and then the `mysql_insert_id()` is called in both threads, it will still return the correct id for each thread.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply not possible. Nothing can happen at the same time in a program.

What is possible is to:

- Start a database transaction
- perform your first query
- retrieve the table's key; if it's an autoincrement, there are built-in ways to retrieve the last inserted key in every database API
- perform your second query using the retrieved key as a parameter
- Commit the transaction; But if an error occurred, you need to rollback the whole transaction

This is how it is done, and it behaves exactly like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

How about a link table?

```
users_customers
user_id | customer_id
=====================
 1      |  648785552
 5      |  145778304
 4      |  654566055
```

You can then join the tables together using this table, for example like this:

```
SELECT users.name, customers.address
  FROM users
  JOIN users_customers
    ON users_customers.user_id = users.id
  JOIN customers
    ON users_customers.customer_id = customers.id
```